# Change JDK Home on Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans

Recently I copied Netbeans 8.2 to new computer and unfortunately the java path are different from previous. My machine running on Windows 10 x64. And when I running netbeans64.exe on `bin` folder than two popups appear

```
cannot locate java installation in specified jdkhome:C:\Users\root\Workspace\root\idk\java\jdk\1.8\bin\
```

After that, I choose to use default version, than another popup appear

```
cannot find java 1.8 or higher
```

I've follow instruction to change on `/etc/netbeans.conf` as below

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Users\root\Workspace\root\idk\java\jdk\1.8\bin\"
```

But it doesn't works. I can assuring you that inside the folder contains java.exe which is version 1.8

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

I had registered that path above on `System Environment Variables`

I have tried to use parameter `--jdkhome` but still got the same result.

What wrong with my Netbeans? Any other suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`jdkhome` should point to the root of the JDK folder, not the bin folder inside it.

So it should be:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Users\root\Workspace\root\idk\java\jdk\1.8\"
```

or

```
--jdkhome C:\Users\root\Workspace\root\idk\java\jdk\1.8
```